# Error generating R file in Netbeans and Eclips on Ubuntu

Tags: android, netbeans, ubuntu

Hi have tried to set up an IDE to do some Android programming. But the R file isnt being generated. I have tried clean build re-downloading the SDK e.t.c and I still cant work out why the R file isnt being built.

```
---------
Handling aidl files...
No AIDL files to compile.
----------
Handling RenderScript files...
No RenderScript files to compile.
----------
Handling Resources...
Generating resource IDs...
/home/User/android-sdks/tools/ant/build.xml:560: The following error           occurred  while executing this line:
/home/user/android-sdks/tools/ant/build.xml:589: Execute failed: 
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/User/android-sdks/platform-tools/aapt" (in directory "/home/jakecunningham/NetBeansProjects/tesr"): error=2, No such     file or directory
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
```

Comment: your setup seems messed up. The Android Asset Packaging Tool fails with " No such     file or directory" that's why the R file is not generated.

Answer (score 1):

clean and build the project. maybe it can help you.